# Using Integer value in MDC object

Tags: java, spring, logging, slf4j, mdc

I was using MDC for logging in my spring boot application. Along with that I was also maintaining a graph. I was fetching the values from MDC to draw the graph. It requires Integer values not the string values. I don't want to make use of String values and then type caste it explicitly after fetching the values for the graph reason being the code may break during type casting as it may contain null values (even though there would be no such scenario as I have kept the default value as "0" but still I want to avoid this).

If I try
`MDC.put("Speed", "0");`
It works fine.
But it shows error for
`MDC.put("Speed", 0);`

Please tell how can I put an integer value in the MDC object.

Comment: MDC is meant for logging and the implementations of MDC that I know of only support strings as keys and as values. That means that the only way to store an integer value in an MDC is to convert it into a string and if you need the integer value back you need to convert the string back into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

MDC only supports string values as keys and values. What you can do instead, to avoid type casting errors for null values, is to use [Integer class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) instead of the primitive int.